# Xamarin Studio 5.9.7 (build 9) Issues

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have two issues since upgrading to Xamarin Studio 5.9.7 (build 9).  I have an xamarin forms app in development.

1. I am getting Foundation.MonoTouchException when trying to run my iOS code in the simulator. Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.

How do I accomplish this?

2. I rebuilt my xamarin forms iOS app and it's size grew from 17MB to 41MB. Has anyone else observed similar behavior? The app store version grew from 50 to 150MB!

Thanks

Comment: Did you find something about this?

Comment: No, not yet. I'll post when I do. Please do the same.

Comment: I tried adding these two lines near the end of FinishedLaunching   var mainController = new UIViewController(); 
Window.RootViewController = mainController;  But then received ModelNotImplementedException when executing the second line.

Comment: The last version of Xcode 7.0.1 could solve you app weight prolem

Comment: That did not help, but thanks any way.  Any luck with the MonoTouchException?

Comment: Hi, yes. At the end in the app class constructor of the shared project the first thing i do is to set the MainPage.

Comment: Mind showing me the line of code?

Comment: I post it as an answer, hope it helps, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the doubling in size of the ipa file is attributable to creating both 32 and 64 bit versions of the app.

A temporary workaround for the Foundation.MonoTouchException is to change the Linker Behavior to Link SDK assemblies only from Link All Assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue,

In the main class app at the shared project first of all set the MainPage, like this.

```
namespace XXXApp
{
    public class XXXApp : Application
        {
            public XXXApp ()
            {
                MainPage = new xxContentPage();
            }
        }
}
```

Hope it helps